# Newsletter mailing service for a rails app that needs control over list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, newsletter, mailchimp

I would like to be able to manage my own subscriber list and send newsletters from the email list in my database. At the same time I would like stats and the high rate of deliverability that a services like mailchimp provide. Things like WYSIWYG email designers are not important to me as the emails will be generated by the rails app. What commercial service would be best for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use mailchip with the gibbon gem https://github.com/amro/gibbon